# How to prevent the logged in user to access the profile of other user by simply changing the id in url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I've build one template, custom links for all users ( subscribers ), give the permission to log in 
( email and password ). After they log in, the same template with custom links and redirects goes to every user.
What i try to do is to prevent the logged in user to access the profile of other user with changing the name in the url.
I try Members and Ultimate member plugins with *"can't view other member profiles"* but it didn't work out for me
I try with custom role and permissions, same thing.

example of my case is:
logged in user has his own url like my-site.com/user-1. If he change it to my-site/user-2 he can access the profile of user 2/3/4 etc

This is for subscribers role in wordpress

Comment: Why do you include the ID in the url at all? Surely your software already knows what the ID is for the logged in user, just load the profile with that. This also allows the url for _anyone_ to access their own profile to be the exact same link. If you really need the ID to be in the URL for some reason, then just simply check if the logged in user matches the ID in the url.

Comment: Check if your logged user id matches with the profile page id, or avoid the page id at all and get from session.

Answer (score 0):

Store the user_id of the user who is logged in into the session variable.

Check if the $_SESSION['user_id'] matches the user_id present in the url.

If it's different, print *"can't view other member profiles"*